# What do the TestNG exit codes mean?

Tags: testng

I got an exit code of 2 when when I ran my TestNG test suite.  However, according to the output, no tests failed.  (Actually, it was run through TeamCity, in a Windows Command-Line step, but I don't think that should make a difference.)

In another run (same test suite on a different System Under Test) I got an exit code of 3.  In this case, some tests did fail.

I've googled around and looked at the [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html), but can't find any information on what TestNG exit codes mean.

What do they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TestNG exit codes can be summarized as below

```
/**
 * |---------------------|---------|--------|-------------|------------------------------------------|
 * | FailedWithinSuccess | Skipped | Failed | Status Code | Remarks                                  |
 * |---------------------|---------|--------|-------------|------------------------------------------|
 * | 0                   | 0       | 0      | 0           | Passed tests                             |
 * | 0                   | 0       | 1      | 1           | Failed tests                             |
 * | 0                   | 1       | 0      | 2           | Skipped tests                            |
 * | 0                   | 1       | 1      | 3           | Skipped/Failed tests                     |
 * | 1                   | 0       | 0      | 4           | FailedWithinSuccess tests                |
 * | 1                   | 0       | 1      | 5           | FailedWithinSuccess/Failed tests         |
 * | 1                   | 1       | 0      | 6           | FailedWithinSuccess/Skipped tests        |
 * | 1                   | 1       | 1      | 7           | FailedWithinSuccess/Skipped/Failed tests |
 * |---------------------|---------|--------|-------------|------------------------------------------|
 */
```

There are some issues in the current released version of TestNG viz., 6.12. This has been fixed by me as part of the pull request https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1578

The next upcoming version of TestNG viz., 6.13 onwards, the exit codes will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/latest/constant-values.html#org.testng.ITestResult.CREATED) the current exit codes are:

```java
public static final int     CREATED                     -1
public static final int     FAILURE                     2
public static final int     SKIP                        3
public static final int     STARTED                     16
public static final int     SUCCESS                     1
public static final int     SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE_FAILURE  4
```